# Myfaces/Omnifaces resource handlers weird behaviour

Tags: jsf-2.2, myfaces, omnifaces

We are using omnifaces (latest snapshot) resource handlers to combine and unmap resource handlers

```
    <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CombinedResourceHandler</resource-handler>
    <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CDNResourceHandler</resource-handler>                
    <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.UnmappedResourceHandler</resource-handler>
```

(Also using Unmapped but it does not apply to this page)

From time to time, when projectStage is production we have broken css includes.

This is normal production html (formatted and indented):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/javax.faces.resource/eNptjMEKgzAQRL8ou63Si3-TriMKiQm724PgxxcKGtDehnnzpuqSMUWBhXcpbq6xDj4jg8RsryceWryQJnITJZXPOKWoCDKunLFBg8Lg3NGDf4nysv4bn3_BkCDOT-rpdasP_QtAUUrT.css?ln=omnifaces.combined&amp;v=1431853580000" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/eNp9UMsSwiAM_KKS8XXx6kd4Rpq2VCDIQ6czfrzQaunU0VM2u5uwxDqpseEC_bG_RXQDTIX1_ml_aJVVsZXGrzwFZoG0kRM_o0z3HgRpTSY3F6Lgg-MWdmzH9pDEmWJajh6hKNaN4g4rUZuiVx4VigCbNHn4oj_TJRPIWmF6VwZyS5xdXdBqK7i5cw8LPEZs_UMG0aGDAlcf_7N54eooXHGAqbxPceYynLijmFIn6gXsJJuf.js?ln=omnifaces.combined&amp;v=1443076786000"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/javax.faces.resource/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/javax.faces.resource/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/javax.faces.resource/css/estilos.css?version=1443076733865" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/javax.faces.resource/css/styles.css?version=1443076733865" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/javax.faces.resource/css/icons/icons.css" />
```

And this is broken code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/javax.faces.resource/eNptjMEKgzAQRL8ou63Si3-TriMKiQm724PgxxcKGtDehnnzpuqSMUWBhXcpbq6xDj4jg8RsryceWryQJnITJZXPOKWoCDKunLFBg8Lg3NGDf4nysv4bn3_BkCDOT-rpdasP_QtAUUrT.css?ln=omnifaces.combined&amp;v=1431700834000" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/eNp9j9EOwiAMRb8IGp2--DcInWMCRQomS_x4mYuOzOhTb--5bdOYrMdeaeTTeCuYJliKHPkRfzARXbnYwJvMKmcwMmjynsLcnIky56QidLKTB6jwY0lvXxntqJjeqYRCm7BywehQZ9jVyeOX_Z5ej4M1Dutdmym1ek4N2bu9VuGuGBq9eeTPgiY1UL7iBEup7AlS-4D0.js?ln=omnifaces.combined&amp;v=1442328192000"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/javax.faces.resource/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/javax.faces.resource/javax.faces.resource/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.m" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/javax.faces.resource/css/estilos.css?version=1443087413884" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/javax.faces.resource/css/styles.css?version=1443087413884" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/javax.faces.resource/css/icons/icons.css" />
```

Note that boostrap css is broken, javax.faces.resource is 2 times and the file name is not complete.

We don't have an idea if this is myfaces (2.2.8) or omnifaces (latest snapshot). It does not happen in development mode and it only happens in production from time to time (maybe 2%). It must be something related with dates but we don't know.

This is the relevant info from web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.CDN_RESOURCE_HANDLER_URLS</param-name>
    <param-value>
        cloudflare-cdn:bootstrap-select/1.3.5/bootstrap-select.min.css=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.3.5/bootstrap-select.min.css,
        cloudflare-cdn:bootstrap-select/1.3.5/bootstrap-select.min.js=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.3.5/bootstrap-select.min.js,
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.CDN_RESOURCE_HANDLER_DISABLED</param-name>
    <param-value>#{facesContext.application.projectStage == 'Development'}</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.COMBINED_RESOURCE_HANDLER_DISABLED</param-name>
    <param-value>#{facesContext.application.projectStage == 'Development'}</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.COMBINED_RESOURCE_HANDLER_EXCLUDED_RESOURCES</param-name>
    <param-value>
        bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css,
        dashboard/dashboard.css,
        css/estilos.css,css/styles.css,
        font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css,
        css/icons/icons.css,fancybox/3b1/jquery.fancybox.js,fancybox/3b1/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.COMBINED_RESOURCE_HANDLER_CACHE_TTL</param-name>
    <param-value>3600000</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: It happens with random css includes, not only with bootstrap

Comment: How is the bootstrap CSS declared? How is CDNResourceHandler configured?

Comment: We have this in our master template:
            <h:outputStylesheet  name="cloudflare-cdn/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" />
            <h:outputStylesheet  name="font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
            <h:outputStylesheet  name="bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

            <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Paprika' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>

            <h:outputStylesheet  name="css/estilos.css?version=#{startup.time}"   />
            <h:outputStylesheet name="css/styles.css?version=#{startup.time}"/>

Comment: We also have a custom headRenderer to always include some css/scripts:
@ResourceDependencies({
    @ResourceDependency(library="primefaces-bootstrap", name="theme.css"),
    @ResourceDependency(library="primefaces", name="jquery/jquery.js"),
    @ResourceDependency(library="primefaces", name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js"),
    @ResourceDependency(library="primefaces", name="primefaces.js"),
    @ResourceDependency(library="primefaces", name="primefaces.css"),
})
public class HeadRenderer extends Renderer {

Comment: --included in the question--

Comment: Combined and CDN can't be it. Unmapped would be a probable suspect (when unmapped resource is passed back again through the unmapped resource handler, i.e. a double unmap whereby `unmapRequestPath()` runs twice on `.xhtml` mapping, having exactly the same length as the missing part) although I don't see how the problem could be triggered (have to check MyFaces source first, my guess would be state saving hiccup). What exactly do you mean with *"Also using Unmapped but it does not apply to this page"*?

Comment: Sorry, i meant CDN, it does not apply to this page because I'm not using any cdn mapped resource in this page

Comment: Ok, it didn't happen again once I removed the CDNResourceHundler.

Comment: Thank you for the clue. I will investigate this.

Comment: I can't explain why it happened as I can't reproduce it. I have at least committed a theoretical fix https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/ca3356e4640271b50345410954681655a2985b92 Can you try today's 2.2 snapshot on this?

Comment: I've been working with it today and so far no error, but as I told you it just happened very few times, about 2% of the times after the server is started, so I will need more testing

Comment: BTW, you made CDI 1.1 a required dependency of omnifaces 2.2, but I'm stuck in TomEE which is still CDI 1.0 and there is an ugly startup error when it tries to  parse the scan in beans.xml (but everything seems to work right).
You fixed 2 errors that I needed fixed in the snapshot, would it be possible a backport to 2.1 version?